# JavaScript function called object with lower-case "o"

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I just watched an introductory JavaScript [lecture](http://yui.zenfs.com/theater/crockford-tjpl-2.m4v) from Douglas Crockford, in which he mentions a function called `object` that should be used to create a new object linked to an object as its parameter. I would guess what he means by that is that if I say

```
var objB = object(objA);
```

The `objB`'s internal `[[prototype]]` reference is set to `objA`, although he didn't explicitly formulate it like that.

On the other hand, I have read his [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002AWX8BO), in which he doesn't mention such a function at all and instead presents his own way of creating an object from a prototype, defining following function :

```
Object.create = function(o) {
   var F = function() {};
   F.prototype = o;
   return new F();
}
```

Essentially taking advantage of the behavior of the `new` operator that sets the internal `[[prototype]]` link of the newly created object to whatever the constructor function's `prototype` property points to.

My question is why would he omit a built-in function and invent his own way to do the same thing. Is the former call to `object` function really equivalent to

```
var objB = Object.create(objA);
```

Or is there some slight difference ?

Comment: I'm on firefox 7, and object({test: 'blah'}); just throws an error about 'object is not defined'. Perhaps 'object' is a function that he created?

Comment: That's exactly right. I should have tried it as well :$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two functions are one and the same, and neither are built in to JavaScript.  See Crockford's [article](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) describing why he switched between the different naming conventions.

Edit from the future: I saw this old answer and wanted to point out that [Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) is indeed a native (and very important) ES5 method.

Comment: Very helpful to see the history. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. And here is "simplified" explanation:

The thing is, everything in javascript is an object and inherits from `Object`.

Also you can look at "function" as directive which defines new type of object, actually constructor of object if you are using new keyword. If you don't use new keyword and call function like in example below

```
function doSomething(){
  alert("works");
}
```

javascript engine will create object doSomething which will contain `prototype` property, this prototype is defined type of object doSomething and it contains constructor which is created by javascript developer with code above. For bult in functions or prototypes, constructors have native code